# Convert countNonZero returned value to percentage

Tags: c++, opencv

Good day,

I have a collection of images stored in edgeStack (vector) with dimensions of 64x64 = 4096. The vector is holding a set of output images produced by canny edge detection.

I would like to compute the percentage of white pixels by using countNonZero as following line. I am converting to string datatype as well since I am going to use putText to display at the bottom of respective frame.

```
string percentage = to_string(double(countNonZero(edgeStack[i]) / 4096) * 100);
```

It doesn't give me the desirable result, instead, I am getting 0 all the time. (See screenshot 1)
[image: Screenshot 1]

So I tried to reduce 4096 to 2 as following manner and I am getting a number > 0.

```
string percentage = to_string(double(countNonZero(edgeStack[i]) / 2) * 100);
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Lastly, my question is why cant I divide by 4096 to get desirable display of result?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`countNonZero`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) returns integer type, so `countNonZero(...) / 4096` is an integer division (rounding to integer, towards zero). You need floating point division, so you need one of the arguments to be a `double`, for example `countNonZero(...) / 4096.0`.

Comment: Took the liberty of adding url to integer function in question